# Can't access outbox while testing with lettuce

Tags: python, django, lettuce

I am using Lettuce to test one of my applications.

I am testing a module to check if I can send emails.

I did some research and found in the Django documentation an easy way to test it.

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase

class EmailTest(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        # Send message.
        mail.send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False)

        # Test that one message has been sent.
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)

        # Verify that the subject of the first message is correct.
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Subject here')
```

The problem is that I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'outbox'`.

From what I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795529/using-lettuce-how-can-i-verify-that-an-email-sent-from-a-django-web-application#comment19836487_8211588), the problem here is that

> The Django server runs in a different process from the
>   lettuce scripts, which would make the outbox inaccessible.

I did some more research and found a possible solution [here](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/issues/215#issuecomment-3460021).

The guy says this:

```
# in terrain.py
from lettuce import before, after, world
from django.conf import settings

@before.handle_request
    def override_mail_settings(httpd, server):
        settings.EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
```

But I don't know what is my `terrain.py` equivalent.I tried in the `steps.py` file, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find [here](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/blob/master/docs/reference/django.rst) the answer to my problem after some more research.

The only thing I had to do was edit `settings.py` and add this line:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
```